# Not able to generate classes in target/generated-sources

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jpa

[image]

I am trying to integrate **JPAStremaer** for my project, when I build it classes with `ClassName$` is expected to generate, the classes are generated but not accessible to use. I made `target/generated-sources/annotations` as source folder and there is no exclusion criteria as well but still does not work

Comment: Where do you run your project in the IDE?

Comment: Hi, I am using STS 4 please see picture in question desc, I updated it.